# Subscribing to system Bluetooth notifications

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth, notifications

Is it possible to subscribe to system notification that indicates that somebody has sent request to the system to check for exist specific bluetooth service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According blackberry specification. It is impossible.